# Autocomplete selected text not saving as expected ? KnockOut

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, autocomplete

I been working on AutoComplete which actually working cool but when i select something from the displayed list by typing a character in textbox  it is getting placed in textbox . At till this point everything fine

**But issue comes now**

when i tried to save the data in textbox to DB with other fields  . I dont know why only the Characters i typed only getting saved but not the data i selected from displayed list using autocomplete .

**Please have a look at my code & suggest :**

**AutoComplete code**

```
 $('#txtAccountProspectnurture').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/api/NurtureAccount",
                    data: { id: request.term },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.Text,
                                value: item.Value
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                })
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                debugger;
                $('#txtAccountProspectnurture').val(ui.item.label); //here i am gettihg fulltext 
                $('#accountnurtureval').val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
```

**View Model :**

```
 self.btnNurtureAddAccount = function () {
        debugger;
        var nurtureaccountids = $("#accountnurtureval").val()
        self.NurtureAccountId(nurtureaccountids);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/NurtureAccount/',
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      data: ko.toJSON(self), //in this self i am JUST getting single character i entered 
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
    }
```

**My API controller Post method :**

```
 public bool Post(models m)
        {
           //Here in **m.NurtureAccountName** i am getting only typed letter not the complete one
           //my save code here
        }
```

Any suggestions are appreciated

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `select` function, you need to update the viewmodel instead of manually updating values using jQuery.

For exemple if your html is something like this:

```
<input id="txtAccountProspectnurture" data-bind="value: accountProspectnurture, 
                                                 valueUpdate: 'blur'" />
<input id="accountnurtureval" data-bind="value: accountnurture, 
                                         valueUpdate: 'blur'" />
```

You would do in your select:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    viewModel.accountProspectnurture(ui.item.label);
    viewModel.accountnurture(ui.item.value);
    return false;
}
```

And the `span` and `input` would be updated automatically by knockout.

Comment: gotcha mate but used valueupdate : 'blur' in data-bind to my textbox . Please include this code above so i can mark your answer :) cheers .